# Color specific columns in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

All I want to do is make the last three columns of my grid view yellow.  Can I not use an itemstyle in the boundfield because I'm using css?  If not how can I easily do this?  Thanks!

```
   <asp:GridView 
        ID="grdMyProducts"
        DataSourceID = "srcGetMyProducts" 
        CssClass="GridViewStyle"
        AutoGenerateColumns = "false"
        AllowPaging = "false"
        GridLines="None"
        runat="server" >
        <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />    
        <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="EmptyRowStyle" />    
        <PagerStyle CssClass="PagerStyle" />    
        <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="SelectedRowStyle" />    
        <HeaderStyle Wrap="false" CssClass="HeaderStyleFilter" />   
        <EditRowStyle CssClass="EditRowStyle" />    
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AltRowStyle" />
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField
            DataField="DistributorName"
            HeaderText="Distributor" />
        <asp:BoundField
            DataField="Size"
            HeaderText="Size" />
        <asp:BoundField
            DataField="Description"
            HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField
            DataField="Category"
            HeaderText="Category" />
            <ItemStyle BackColor="#f6f17c"/>
        <asp:BoundField
            DataField="Amount"
            HeaderText="Amount" />
            <ItemStyle BackColor="#f6f17c"/>
        <asp:BoundField
            DataField="Unit"
            HeaderText="Unit" />
            <ItemStyle BackColor="#f6f17c"/>
        </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I feel stupid.... It was a mistake in my code.  I was closing the bound field before calling the item style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User **ItemStyle-CSSClass** property of your BoundField.

```
<asp:BoundField  DataField="Category" ItemStyle-CssClass="myStyle"  HeaderText="Category" />
```

and Have this CSS class in your stylesheet

```
.myStyle
{
  background-color:Gray;
  color:Red;
}
```

It should work. I tested it.

Comment: that works.  my example above works as well but I had an error in the code.